# Air purifier: What is the reaction mechanism between HCHO and negative oxygen ion

Tags: reaction-mechanism, purification, oxides

Multiple [government](http://www.tongzhou.gov.cn/tzqrmzf/jkjyxczl/content/0212c01c-a366-4711-b374-d3acfedf695e.html) and commercial sources claim that the negative oxygen ion generated by air purifier can reduce HCHO concentration.

However, on google scholar, I find neither the reaction formula between them nor the reaction speed/efficiency under normal concentration and conditions.

What are some reliable source/common sense on this topic?

To my knowledge HCHO is a reductant so it makes sense that $O_3$ can effectively reduce its concentration. But the negative oxygen ion seems to be a reductant with short half-life and low concentration, casting doubts on its "purifying ability".